# PHP messaging system is slow

Tags: php, ajax

I am building a simple messaging system for my website and it seems to be slow and sometimes crashes the browser. Below is the code.

First i wrote an ajax request to get all user chat from database

```
setInterval(function () {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "get_chat.php",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (response) {
          $(".msgView").html(response);
          if (response !== lastResponse) {
              var audio = new Audio('audio/solemn.mp3')
              audio.play()
          }
          lastResponse = response
      }
  });
```

}, 2000);

here is **get-chat.php**

```
<?php
$us_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];

//echo empty($_SESSION['hash']) ? 'not set' : $_SESSION['hash'];

$hasher = $_SESSION['hash'];

$mesql =<<<EOF
SELECT from_id, message FROM messager WHERE group_hash = '$hasher';
EOF;
$meret = $db->query($mesql);
while ($merow = $meret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $from_id = $merow['from_id'];
    $messages = $merow['message'];


    $usql =<<<EOF
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$from_id';
EOF;
    $uret = $db->query($usql);

    while ($urow = $uret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        $from_fname = $urow['fname'];
        $from_img = $urow['profimages'];


        if ($from_id != $_SESSION['log_id']) {

            echo '
            <div class="recMsgBubble">
                <div class="recBubbleImg"><img src="'.$from_img.'"></div>
                <div class="recBubbleMsg">'.$messages.'</div>
            </div>';
            //<div class='from_bubble'><div class='from_img'><img src='$from_img'></div><p>$messages</p></div><br>
        } else {
            echo '
            <div class="userMsgBubble">
                <div class="userBubbleImg"><img src="'.$from_img.'"></div>
                <div class="userBubbleMsg">'.$messages.'</div>
            </div>';
            //<div class='rep_bubble'><div class='rep_img'><img src='$from_img'></div><p>$messages</p></div><br>
        }
    }
    $csql =<<<EOF
     SELECT * FROM banks WHERE bname = '$from_id';
EOF;
         $cret = $db->query($csql);

         while ($crow = $cret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
             $from_fname = $crow['bname'];
             $from_img = $crow['banklogo'];


             if ($from_id = $from_fname) {

                 echo '<div class="recMsgBubble">
                     <div class="recBubbleImg"><img src="'.$from_img.'">
</div>
                     <div class="recBubbleMsg">'.$messages.'</div>
                 </div>';
             } else {
                 echo '<div class="userMsgBubble">
                     <div class="userBubbleImg"><img src="'.$from_img.'">
</div>
                     <div class="userBubbleMsg">'.$messages.'</div>
                 </div>';
             }
         }
}
?>
```

Also to send the chat, an ajax request is used as below

```
$("#msgSender").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send_chat.php",
    data: $(this).serializeArray(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
    }
});
$('#userMsgField').val("");
});
```

Here is send_chat.php

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userMsgField']) && !empty($_POST['userMsgField']) || isset($_POST['hash']) && !empty($_POST['hash']))
{
$my_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];
$rep_msg = $_POST['userMsgField'];
$hash = $_SESSION['hash'];
$flag = 0;

$sql =<<<EOF
SELECT * FROM connect WHERE (user_one = '$my_id' AND hash = '$hash') OR (user_two = '$my_id' AND hash = '$hash');
EOF;

$ret = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $user_one = $row['user_one'];
    $user_two = $row['user_two'];

    if ($user_one == $my_id)
    {
        $to_id = $user_two;
    }
    else
    {
        $to_id = $user_one;
    }


    $isql =<<<EOF
    INSERT INTO messager (message, group_hash, from_id, flag, to_id) VALUES (:message, :group_hash, :from_id, :flag, :to_id);
EOF;
    $bsql =<<<EOF
    INSERT INTO chatportal (message, group_hash, from_id, flag, to_id) 
VALUES (:message, :group_hash, :from_id, :flag, :to_id); 
EOF;

    $stmt = $db->prepare($isql);
    $bstmt = $db->prepare($bsql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':message', $rep_msg, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':group_hash', $hash, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $stmt->bindValue(':from_id', $my_id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $stmt->bindValue(':flag', $flag, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $stmt->bindValue(':to_id', $to_id, SQLITE3_TEXT);

    $bstmt->bindValue(':message', $rep_msg, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':group_hash', $hash, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':from_id', $my_id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':flag', $flag, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':to_id', $to_id, SQLITE3_TEXT);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $bresult = $bstmt->execute();

    if ($reuslt && $bresult)
    {
        echo "GHood";
    }
}
}
```

I think the reason for it being slow is that it tries to get the messages every 2 seconds. If this is the issue, please how do i fix?

If not what is the solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use `websockets` check [here](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) for instant chat applications, calling server every 2 seconds for each user will cause server load to slow down.

Comment: Do you have access to any tutorial on websockets

Comment: check here https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket, it will help

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan I have read through and i think i would have to build the entire chat from scratch. My question again is that is there a way i can fix the issue with websockets without building from scratch or fix this issue by any other means

Answer (score 1):

PHP messaging system is slow if you build it from scratch. I use JQuery before but after ES7 and ES8 I starting using the native javascript and it was faster than jquery. There are 3 things you can do to at-least speed it up:

1. Do not use the jQuery Ajax use the native Ajax, since jQuery is a very large library to load and risky, to begin with.
2. Buy or use a faster server.
3. Prevent retrieving the entire message conversation every time the user inputs a message. Use a script that would only get the values that were added during the conversation and limit the message history per view.

You can search the ajax syntax from here https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/